# Firestore emulator returning Missing or insufficient permissions, worked last week

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I took a month off from coding in my project. Before I took summer vacation everything was working perfectly. I had working auth (email/password) and was able to write and read data to/from firestore emulator.

I come back from summer vacation authentication still works but reading/writing to firestore emulator just stopped working. Gives me the error "Missing or insufficient permissions".

Litterally no changes since july. Website working on production, suddenly not in development.

Did I miss a breaking update from firestore this summer? Anyone else experiencing similar problems?

I've tried updating firebase and firebase-tools, project builds, only auth is working but firebase keeps throwing errors. My security rules work on production.

Edit: Code where I try to get from firebase. Same code that used to work before.

```
props.firebase
   .assessments()
   .orderBy('name')
   .get()
```

Edit: Security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Everything else only available to logged in users
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true; // Changed to troubleshoot in development
         // request.auth != null;
    }

    // Only allow users to read, update their own user profile
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow update, write: if request.auth != null 
                         && request.auth.uid == userId;

      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }

    // Restrict team visibility to team members
    match /teams/{team} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
                         && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/memberships/$(request.auth.uid+'_'+team) )
    }

    match /tasks/{task} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null 
                         && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.teams[request.resource.data.team];
    }

    
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the security rules you are using.

Comment: Excellent point. I´ve added the security rules below.

Comment: Thanks for those rules. Now also please add the [minimal, standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the error you're getting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I´ve added a simple example, I have a firebase object I´ve been using to fetch and write data to firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve figured it out.

I was using  the

```
experimentalForceLongPolling: true
```

Configuration flag for firestore, since I´m also using Cypress for testing and firebase and Cypress don't mix to well.

Once I removed the experimentalForceLongPolling flag, code started working again, but I´m back to square one testing authenticated pages with Cypress as Firebase Authentication and Cypress don't mix too well.