# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions Using Default Firestore Rules on Localhost Emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a localhost deployment using firebase's emulators (auth, firestore and firebase functions).

I have a form which tries to write to the database and arrives at a `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` Normally Id expect this to be typical `firestore.rules` issue. So I inspected it further and couldnt find any misconfiguration. So to confirm I comment it out to use the default test deployment rule to allow read/write to all docs. (I know this is bad but this was a sanity check). I still have the same error. Im puzzled as to what is making this occur.

The console shows upon saves to my firestore.rules file that changes are applied. So I can rule out the emulator not loading the file properly.
[image]

Here is the code and error produced. When a user wants to submit a Proposal the data is written to the database. For this example I performed both a read and write.

The Error one for each read and write:
[image]

```js
// React modal which attempts to access the firestore db
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs, addDoc, Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, getCurrentUser } from "../services/Firebase";

const ProposalModal = ({
  showModal,
  toggleWindow,
  userAddress,
  tokenid,
  ...props
}) => {
  const referenceDescriptionTextArea = useRef();
  const proposalsCollectionReference = collection(db, "proposals");

  const handleProposalSubmit = async (event) => {
    console.log("handleProposalSubmit");
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      author: getCurrentUser().uid,
      timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
      tokenid: tokenid,
      type: "frenbio",
      description: referenceDescriptionTextArea.current.value,
    };

    console.log("STORING: " + data);

    getDocs(proposalsCollectionReference).then(       //errors
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
    console.log("READING");
    addDoc(proposalsCollectionReference, data).then(   //errors
      (docRef) => {
        console.log(docRef.id); //p4eZcO5QV43IYnigxALJ
        toggleWindow();
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  };
   
   return( //some component render for the modal)
 };
```

My firestore rules:
Initially I created the Proposals ruling to allow writes only to users who are authenticated. Guests can read Proposals freely. The `request.auth != null` seems ok. I have users authenticate with signInWithCustomToken approach which works fine for my app. I reference the user's auth object with `getCurrentUser`. After failing with proposal I opened up read and write for all docs but the error still persists.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   
    // Commented out as R/W was not working
    // match /proposals/{doc} {
    //  allow read: if true;
    //  allow write: request.auth != null;
    // }
    
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;   //Note: Giving full rights still fail
    }
  }
}
```

Is my approach incorrect with the firestorerules, the calles themselves or perhaps something else?

**EDIT: **
Firebase tools verion is 11.9.0.
Here is the full package list

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "serve-all": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@metamask/eth-sig-util": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Could this be related to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4975

Comment: It sounds like it is related to this issue

Comment: Please refer the links here, which describe similar issue and the possible solutions.https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288520/permission-denied-in-firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Use `connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);` in your db instantiation.

Obviously only during dev

Answer (score 0):

You have to retain the match for /databases/{database}/documents that you were given in the initial set of rules to [authenticate the users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication), and as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).Try the below changes to security rules.As you are working with mixed public and private access to the documents, check out this helpful [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#mixed_public_and_private_access) on the configuration details.

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
   }
 }
}
```

You can also check this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) configuring the firestore web client this way:

```
const db = firebaseApp.firestore(); 
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") { console.log("localhost detected!"); 
db.settings({ host: "localhost:8080", ssl: false }); }
```

The Rules Playground is a convenient tool to use as you're exploring new behaviors or quickly validating rules as you write them. It displays a message confirming that access was either allowed or denied according to the parameters you set for the simulation. You can find the documentation for the [rules playground here] [6](https://google.dev/codelabs/firebase-emulator-get-started#2) but all you need to do is insert the simulated location of the path where you want to read/write .

Check a [similar implementation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815313/firestore-emulator-returning-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-worked-last-we) here

Comment: I agree with `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` but that was the first thing I tried. To narrow the issue I it to all users with `if true` . Unfortunately that resulted in the same read/write error issues

Comment: Please refer the links here, which describe similar issue and the possible solutions.https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288520/permission-denied-in-firestore.